# javaScript - Lógica de programação

Tags: javascript, lógica

Estou aprendendo lógica de programação e gostaria de saber como faço para somar os valores que estão dentro do switch por que a variável "vf" não está mostrando o valor final somado corretamente.

A tarefa é pedir para o usuário quantos produtos quiser, a partir do código de 100-106, quando ele digitar 0 significa que é para o programa parar e somar todos os valores e mostrar na tela o valor final.

```js
var c, v, vf = 0.00;

do {
  c = parseInt(prompt("Digite um código de 100 até 106"));

  switch (c) {
    case 100:
      v = 10.90;
      break;
    case 101:
      v = 8.90;
      break;
    case 102:
      v = 14.90;
      break;
    case 103:
      v = 13.90;
      break;
    case 104:
      v = 16.90;
      break;
    case 105:
      v = 22.90;
      break;
    case 106:
      v = 4.90;
      break;

    default:
      document.write("código inexistente");
  }

  vf += v;

} while (c != 0);

document.write("O valor total é de R$" + vf);
```

Comment: Que passar algum apuro **Digite `0` para abandonar o loop.**

Comment: Tenha em mente que o fórum não para trabalho colaborativo!!
Busque fazer perguntas objetivas onde esteja claro o erro / problema!! 
Isso deixa pegadas digitais onde a sua dúvida pode ajuda a comunidade e a novatos a aprender com a sua pergunta!!
E antes de fazer uma pergunta pesquise (pelas tags) se já exitem alguma dúvida similar!
Obrigado por contribuir com a sua pergunta!!

Comment: @pss1suporte tenha em mente que não somos um fórum, sejam novos no site ou não, que leiam o [FAQ da comunidade](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/699/3635)

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento, como está? Verdade! Bem lembrado do [FAQ da comunidade](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/699/faq-da-comunidade). Vou melhorar as minhas revisões do Primeiras Perguntas!! Sucesso!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Então, esse erro está acontecendo porque você está utilizando um do-while, em que ele primeiro realiza a ação, depois checa se continua no loop. E a sequência da sua lógica é:

1. O usuário entra com o valor:

```js
c = parseInt(prompt("Digite um código de 100 até 106"));
```

2. O switch altera o valor de v dependendo do caso

```js
switch (c) {
    case 100:
      v = 10.90;
      break;
...
```

3. Logo em seguida você soma isso ao valor final:

```js
vf += v;
```

4. É verificado no while se o loop continua ou não

```js
while (c != 0)
```

Ou seja, quando você bota o valor de c como 0, para encerrar o loop, ele ainda faz uma última soma ao seu valor final, porque o programa só sabe que é pra parar quando chega no while.

Então se você entrou com 106 e logo em seguida 0, o que vai acontecer é que `v = 4.90` e você vai somar uma primeira vez em `vf += v`, ficando `vf = 4.90`. Só que como c ainda é igual a 106, esse while vai continuar o loop, então mesmo você entrando com 0 depois no prompt, vai ocorrer outra soma `vf += v`, sendo que vf ainda é 4.90 e v também, então o resultado final fica 9.80 , mesmo você tendo adicionado uma vez o 106.

Da pra contornar isso entrando com uma condição nessa soma, em que só vai ser somado se c for diferente de 0:

```js
if (c !== 0) {
    vf += v;
}
```

O código todo ficaria assim :

```js
var c, v, vf = 0.00;

do {
  c = parseInt(prompt("Digite um código de 100 até 106"));

  switch (c) {
    case 100:
      v = 10.90;
      break;
    case 101:
      v = 8.90;
      break;
    case 102:
      v = 14.90;
      break;
    case 103:
      v = 13.90;
      break;
    case 104:
      v = 16.90;
      break;
    case 105:
      v = 22.90;
      break;
    case 106:
      v = 4.90;
      break;

    default:
      document.write("código inexistente");
  }

  if (c !== 0) {
    vf += v;
  }

} while (c != 0);

document.write("O valor total é de R$" + vf);
```

Seria melhor nesse problema utilizar um while em vez de um do-while, mas como você está praticando sua lógica não tem problema !!